# Office 365 timezone for New Zealand is 2 hours too early

Tags: office-365, office-online

In Office 365, via settings cog -> your app settings -> calendar -> general -> region and time zone

I've set the time zone to "(UTC+12) Auckland, Wellington"

But its currently displaying 2am as the current time instead of 4am.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?